# Electrical problem

Tags: wiring

When I plug something in to the same wall as my appliances it causes the other appliances to just shut off. I need help. The house was built in 1989. I would like to use a toaster or coffee maker without my oven, microwave and internet shutting off.

Comment: Wrong site. This is not a design question. Move to DIY.

Comment: When things "shut off", what do you do to make things work again? (a) Press a "reset" button on a receptacle or breaker; (b) flip a breaker back ON; (c) unplug the item you plugged in and everything else "just works"?

Comment: Can you tell us which receptacles shut off when you plug something in on that wall, which receptacles *cause that problem* when plugged into, and whether all the receptacles are turned on and off by the same breaker or by different breakers?

Comment: Please tell us a lot more about the circuit breaker(s) which feed these circuits.  That is to say, which circuit breaker(s), if shut off, will disconnect power to these outlets? *This could actually be something dangerous, by the way*.

Answer (score 2):

As it appears from the tone of your question you should probably bring in a professional electrician to diagnose the issue that you have. As it stands this circuit switching behavior could very well be a huge safety issue. The reason being is that electrical circuits that can switch themselves like this are typically intermittent connections that can arc and generate excess heat that melts wire insulation and outlet parts and could even catch fire.

With that point of concern on the table I would like to suggest that the statement that your house was built in 1989 puts it squarely in the time period when back stab wiring connections were beginning to be used. You would even likely find the use of 12AWG wire using such type of connections. It is now common knowledge that these back stab type connections are unreliable, especially the ones using 12AWG wire. *In fact the 12AWG wiring is not even allowed for use in back stab connections these days.*

If you feel confident and understand how to safely work with electrical wiring you may want to investigate all the outlets on the circuits that are giving you problems. See if they are back stab type and in particular those with the 12AWG size wire. If you find that you will want to replace all of those outlets with quality new outlets that have screw terminals or screw clamp type terminals for the wires.

Make sure that when you endeavor to undertake a task to change outlets to follow these guidelines.

1. Make sure to shut off any circuits at the power panel before taking anything apart.
2. Make sure to have plenty of light in the work area where an outlet electrical box will be worked on.
3. When you initially open any electrical box make sure you use the modern convenience of smart phones to take pictures of each electrical box **before** you disconnect any wires. Also it can be a good idea to label each wire with a numbered or colored tag. Multiple pictures from various angles will be very helpful for you if you run into a strange situation and need to come back here for additional guidance.
4. It can be very helpful to purchase a small testing tool called a Non Contact Voltage Detector that you use to ensure that all wires in the electrical box are shut off before you start disconnecting any wires.
5. Lastly when removing old back stabbed outlets do not go crazy with wire cutters to remove them. Instead figure out how the stab wire releases work and use them to free the wires.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Michael Karas' answer, it may be one 15A circuit breaker controls them all. In that case, someone will have to run a new wire to some of the outlets. That will (or will) not be a lot of work. (I had similar problem, if the microwave and hair dryer were used at the same time-different outlets, my breaker would strip. Running a new wire to the microwave outlet solved the problem)

Comment: You mean a new *cable*.  A wire is one of the things inside the cable.